Identify type of 4 pin fan connector
I have this 4 pin fan connector but it is a bit smaller than a regular PC fan. Trying to identify the name of the connector to order.


The plug I am looking for is the one on the left. The one on the right is a regular PC fan connector.



More pictures here.

The pitch is 2.5 mm
My Identiconn utility identifies is as a JST XH connector.

{Source: JST}
The part number of the housing is JST XHP-4.
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/XHP-4/683353
